# What happens if I use socket.io allover the app?

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js

I am writing an android app using Java and for the back-end I chose socket.io in node js.
I just want to ask what happens if I socket.io instead of rest-api?

Comment: do you mean you want to write your entire app with websockets???

Comment: Yest, because I think its much faster and could provide me real-time communication .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using socket.io as the main communication system is not a good choice because the communication system is always open.
now imagine 1000 people want a data trough sockets, it will slowdown your server and sometimes cause server crashes.

Comment: You can have [millions](https://alexhultman.medium.com/millions-of-active-websockets-with-node-js-7dc575746a01) of websocket connections on consumer hardware. Thinking that your server will choke on 1000 clients shouldn't keep you from using websockets, if that suits your software otherwise.

Comment: @Kayaman I know, we are using it everyday over lots of apps, but he wants to use it instead of rest api. That is scary if you write your entire app with it.

Comment: Well it shouldn't be scary to a professional developer. They should be able to tell the pros and cons instead of saying "it will crash your server". This is just a poor answer that suggests websockets are *never* the right choice.

Comment: Well, Edit my answer to to a pro answer!